# Dynamic Bind9 + DHCP

Tags: dns, dhcp

i have been working on setup a server for my internal network, so far i have a working isc-dhcp-server that can upgrade a chrooted BIND9 (on the same machine), i need to add some static entries on the DNS, so users can resolve the websites that resides in our DMZ.

What i had tryed all ready was to modify the /etc/bind/named.conf.local with this info:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

key DHCP_UPDATER {
        algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
        secret "MySuperSecretHash"; (this is not the real value BTW)
};

zone "quality.internal" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/quality.internal.db";
        allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
};

zone "0.10.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/rev.10.10.0.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
};

logging {
        channel query.log {
                file "/var/log/named/query.log";
                severity debug 3;
        };

        category queries { query.log; };
};
```

then i added this 2 entries:

```
zone "ourserver.internal" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/ourserver.internal.db";
};

zone "0.16.172.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/rev.172.16.0.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

So.. i created the files ourserver.internal.db and rev.172.16.0.in-addr.arpa placed them BOTH in /var/lib/bind/ and changed the permisions so the bind user can access them, restated the service... when i do a NSLOOKUP www.ourserver.internal i get:

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.ourserver.internal: NXDOMAIN

BUT when i do a reverse lookup....

Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

5.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa name = www.ourserver.internal
```

I do not understand what's wrong. Some help with this will save me from installing a new DNS server at the DMZ JUST to host internal site names-

TY in advance

BTW: the server i'm using has Ubuntu Server 11.10 fully patched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. looks like after all it was an issue with the /var/lib/bind/ourserver.internal.db file, started from scratch and now it's resolving fast and error free! :), actually i'm leaving here the example i took from other web site:

```
;
;BIND data file for example.com
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. info.example.com. (
                            2007011501        ; Serial
                                  7200        ; Refresh
                                   120        ; Retry
                               2419200        ; Expire
                                604800)        ; Default TTL
;
@        IN        NS        ns1.example.com.
@        IN        NS        ns2.example.com.
example.com.    IN    MX        10        mail.example.com.
example.com.    IN    A        192.168.254.1
ns1                IN    A        192.168.254.1
ns2                IN    A        192.168.254.2
www                IN    CNAME    example.com.
mail               IN    A        192.168.254.1
ftp                IN    CNAME    example.com.
example.com.       IN    TXT      "v=spf1 ip4:192.168.254.1 a mx ~all"
mail               IN    TXT      "v=spf1 a -all"
```